# Stored Procedure return varchar(MAX)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, return-value

I need help to return the 'xmlstring' (varchar(MAX)) from a Stored Procedure. It works fine if I test to count the number of 'xmlstring', but how do I get the actual string returned insted?
`ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_test
AS

    DECLARE @Ret int

    SELECT @Ret = COUNT(xmlstring) FROM database WHERE (id = 1)

    RETURN @Ret`


I wan't to do something like this, but it's not correct:
`ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_test
AS

    DECLARE @Ret varchar(MAX)

    SELECT @Ret = TOP (1) xmlstring FROM database WHERE (id = 1)

    RETURN @Ret`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah something like that:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_test AS
DECLARE @Ret varchar(MAX)
SELECT  TOP (1) xmlstring FROM database WHERE (id = 1)
```

You don't need a return unless it's a function

The select statement will be returned, and you can put more than one, those are call ResultSet

Comment: I want to use it as a function (if possible).

Comment: So lose the word procedure and put function instead:

Comment: If I use 'ExecuteScalar()' I get the first cell in the first row and it's works the same way as using the RETURN. (How could I miss this? Problem solved!)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP (1) xmlstring FROM database WHERE (id = 1)
```

If you want to set a local scalar variable the way you currently are it needs to be

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_test AS
DECLARE @Ret varchar(MAX)
Set @Ret = TOP (1) xmlstring FROM database WHERE (id = 1)
RETURN @Ret
```

Comment: I get an error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'." with my code above and with your change to "Set" instead of "SELECT".

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_test AS
SELECT xmlstring FROM database WHERE (id = 1)
```

You don't need a variable, and you don't need TOP, unless id is not unique (in which case, you might consider something besides TOP, such as MIN(), MAX(), or some other filter criteria, as you can't really predict which record TOP will return)